# NewtonSoft JsonContract OnDeserializedCallbacks not called for primitive types?

Tags: c#, json.net

After a DateTime is deserialized, I want to do some stuff in a central place. So I thought to hook an callback to the contract, but they are never called.
Any ideas?

```
    public class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
        {
            var result = base.CreateContract(objectType);
            var primContract = result as JsonPrimitiveContract;
            if (primContract != null && primContract.CreatedType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                primContract.OnDeserializingCallbacks.Add((o, context) =>
                {
                    var test = o;
                });
                primContract.OnDeserializedCallbacks.Add((o, context) =>
                {
                    var test = o;
                });
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

The callbacks are added but never called.

Answer (score 1):

You're right - I was able to reproduce this (demo [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m05CVC)).

Even stranger, for non-primitive types that have a `TypeConverter` installed (such as `System.Drawing.Color`) and so are handled by [`JsonStringContract`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonStringContract.htm), the `OnSerializing` and `OnSerialized` callbacks are called, but not the corresponding deserialization callbacks.

You might want to [report an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues).

In the meantime, you could subclass [`IsoDateTimeConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_IsoDateTimeConverter.htm) or some other converter inheriting from [`DateTimeConverterBase`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_DateTimeConverterBase.htm) and add the callbacks there:

```
public class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var result = base.CreateContract(objectType);
        var primContract = result as JsonPrimitiveContract;
        if (primContract != null 
            && (primContract.CreatedType == typeof(DateTime) || primContract.CreatedType == typeof(DateTime?))
            && primContract.Converter == null
           )
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Adding {0} callbacks for {1}", primContract.ToString(), objectType.ToString());
            var converter = new MyIsoDateTimeConverter();
            converter.OnDeserializingCallbacks.Add((o, context) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Deserializing " + o);
            });
            converter.OnDeserializedCallbacks.Add((o, context) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Deserialized " + o);
            });
            primContract.Converter = converter;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class MyIsoDateTimeConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    private List<SerializationCallback> _onDeserializingCallbacks;
    private List<SerializationCallback> _onDeserializedCallbacks;

    public IList<SerializationCallback> OnDeserializingCallbacks
    {
        get
        {
            if (_onDeserializingCallbacks == null)
            {
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _onDeserializingCallbacks, new List<SerializationCallback>(), null);
            }
            return _onDeserializingCallbacks;
        }
    }

    public IList<SerializationCallback> OnDeserializedCallbacks
    {
        get
        {
            if (_onDeserializedCallbacks == null)
            {
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _onDeserializedCallbacks, new List<SerializationCallback>(), null);
            }
            return _onDeserializedCallbacks;
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
        if (value != null && value is DateTime)
        {
            if (_onDeserializingCallbacks != null)
            {
                foreach (var callback in _onDeserializingCallbacks)
                    callback(value, serializer.Context);
            }
            if (_onDeserializedCallbacks != null)
            {
                foreach (var callback in _onDeserializedCallbacks)
                    callback(value, serializer.Context);
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Note that, for types such as `DateTime` that have value semantics, it doesn't make sense to call an `OnDeserializing` event after the object has been constructed but before it is populated, since the object is fully populated upon construction.  Thus I called both events after deserialization.

Also, read through [Serializing Dates in JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) to make sure `IsoDateTimeConverter` will meet your needs.

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qqo0jD).

Comment: What I want to achieve is this: I receive now UTC datetimes (Kind = UTC) from my rest api. I want these to convert to a local datetime using a timezone configured per user of my webapplication. I want to do that in a central location. But as you pointed out, I can't do this on deserialzing, because datetime is already constructed there and I can't return a new instance. So I think I need to create a converter although I am fine with the default datetime string semantics.

Comment: @JaapMosselman - Creating your own `DateTime` converter and making the change at the end of `ReadJson()` would seem to be the way to go then.  If you need help with that, you could ask another question, as the recommended format for questions on stack overflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).